# Computational cost of arithmetics in R

Tags: r

What is the computational cost of arithmetic operations in R? E.g. does multiplication of two 32-bit integers take constant time with regard to their magnitude?

Comment: Are you asking other people to google for you?

Comment: Have you googled? There is none

Comment: Can you please clarify/expand/give a little more context? (The context may be obvious to some readers, but it isn't to me) Constant-time with respect to what?  Magnitude?  I think the answer will be "the same as the time complexity of 32-bit integer multiplication in any standard language, as these are essentially translated directly to machine operations".

Comment: I would imagine you would find the examples in here: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: ... you could rephrase your question as "what is the time-complexity (or how do I determine it)" rather than "how can I find documentation" ... ?

Comment: Joseph, not helpful. Your link relates to the definition of the language, nothing with regard to the official implementation of it and the way the implementation handles arithmetic.

Comment: I'm not sure why the computational complexity of arithmetic functions would be different for R than in general. This may be your best resource https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Arithmetic_functions

Comment: Ben, I have rephrased the question by your suggestion. How did you arrive at your answer?

Comment: Hack-R, that is exactly what I want to make sure. R has a lot of boxing for expressions, for example lazy evaluation. Would the boxing introduce significant overhead as to change the complexity?

Comment: @Hack-R: ?????? (as far as I know, I'm not an admin ...)

Comment: This question is meaningless. Complexity is how fast computational time increases as the input data's size increases. But the input data are two 32 bit integers! There's no variation in their size!

Comment: Can anyone explain the many down votes? From the fact that I got a satisfying answer I can tell my question can be understood; from the fact that the answer points to the source code I guess it's not something one can answer by merely googling.

Comment: Actually, I have to agree that technically your question doesn't really  make sense (as @Paul comments above).  If you said something like "computational cost" it might make more sense.

Comment: Why wouldn't the _time_ complexity be constant. It's a single operation on input of _fixed_ _size_, you do it once - it's done.  It doesn't matter how long it takes, it's still constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/arithmetic.c#L346) you'll see that in R, integer multiplication simply calls the C integer-multiplication operator. So the only answer I can give to "what is the computational cost of integer multiplication in R?" is "the same as the computational cost of integer multiplication with whatever C compiler has been used to compile R"; the answer to *that* question will usually be "the same as the computational cost of the integer-multiplication machine instruction (e.g., `IMUL`) on the particular chip on which you are running".

Comment: Is the source code the only recourse? Do the developers not document the complexity behavior of the standard implementation?

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) No. (3) While a lot of R is not as well documented as I'd like, it doesn't seem odd to me that this isn't explicitly documented ... I doubt (although I could certainly be wrong) that the time complexity of integer multiplication is explicitly documented for (e.g.) C or Python either, as all either of them do is translate the operation to the corresponding machine instruction. (Just curious, can you point to analogous documentation for some mainstream language?)

Comment: That's reasonable. I'm not aware of such analogous documentation either.

Comment: actually, I'm reminded that the answer is a little more complicated for Python (e.g. see [here](https://www.quora.com/How-long-does-integer-multiplication-take-as-compared-to-addition)) as the native integer type tries to be arbitrary-magnitude whenever it can ...